# Error installing postgresql (subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 64)

Tags: package-management, dpkg, postgresql

I'm getting an error when trying to install postgresql. I'll explain what I've found below, but here's the entire output:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  postgresql-9.4 postgresql-common postgresql-contrib-9.4
Suggested packages:
  postgresql-doc oidentd ident-server locales-all libdbd-pg-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgresql postgresql-9.4 postgresql-common postgresql-contrib
  postgresql-contrib-9.4
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,436 kB of archives.
After this operation, 21.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-common.
(Reading database ... 408486 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-common_169.pgdg14.04+1_all.deb ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/bin/pg_config to /usr/bin/pg_config.libpq-dev by postgresql-common'
Unpacking postgresql-common (169.pgdg14.04+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-9.4.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-9.4_9.4.4-1.pgdg14.04+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-9.4 (9.4.4-1.pgdg14.04+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql_9.4+169.pgdg14.04+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql (9.4+169.pgdg14.04+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-contrib-9.4.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-contrib-9.4_9.4.4-1.pgdg14.04+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-contrib-9.4 (9.4.4-1.pgdg14.04+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-contrib.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-contrib_9.4+169.pgdg14.04+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-contrib (9.4+169.pgdg14.04+1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up postgresql-common (169.pgdg14.04+1) ...
Illegal option -d
Usage: install [<option>...] [<path>]
Install exercism client to <path>. Default:
  * determined interactively if possible
  * /usr/local/bin if run as root
  * /usr/local/bin if it is writable
  * /home/collin/bin otherwise
Options:
  -v <version>           Install client version <version>.      Default: v2.2.0
  -o <operating system>  Install client for <operating system>. Default: linux
  -a <architecture>      Install client for <architecture>.     Default: 64bit
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 64
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-9.4:
 postgresql-9.4 depends on postgresql-common (>= 142~); however:
  Package postgresql-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package postgresql-9.4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql:
 postgresql depends on postgresql-9.4; however:
  Package postgresql-9.4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package postgresql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-contrib-9.4:
 postgresql-contrib-9.4 depends on postgresql-9.4 (= 9.4.4-1.pgdg14.04+1); however:
  Package postgresql-9.4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package postgresql-contrib-9.4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-contrib:
 postgresql-contrib depends on postgresql-contrib-9.4; however:No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                 No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

  Package postgresql-contrib-9.4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package postgresql-contrib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-common
 postgresql-9.4
 postgresql
 postgresql-contrib-9.4
 postgresql-contrib
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It looks like it's unable to install postgresql-common, and that leads to all the "dependency problems" it references as it tries to install the other postgresql packages. Just before the error with installing postgresql-common, it spits out the following error:

```
Setting up postgresql-common (169.pgdg14.04+1) ...
Illegal option -d
Usage: install [<option>...] [<path>]
Install exercism client to <path>. Default:
  * determined interactively if possible
  * /usr/local/bin if run as root
  * /usr/local/bin if it is writable
  * /home/collin/bin otherwise
Options:
  -v <version>           Install client version <version>.      Default: v2.2.0
  -o <operating system>  Install client for <operating system>. Default: linux
  -a <architecture>      Install client for <architecture>.     Default: 64bit
```

I believe this is referring to the [exercism.io](http://help.exercism.io/installing-the-cli-on-linux.html) client I've previously installed. Strangely, when I then try running `service postgresql start` (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/83404/410817)), it spits out the same error. After I purge all the postgresql packages, when I try `service postgresql start`, it just says `postgresql: unrecognized service`.

All this makes me think that the exercism client has something to do with the problem. I don't have much experience with Ubuntu, so I don't know what to make of that and I might be wrong. I've tried removing all references to exercism, including the exercism file in my $HOME/bin, and the corresponding addition to my $PATH that was placed in my bash profile. Doing so hasn't changed any of my results at all. The exercism site doesn't seem to have any support regarding uninstalling the client so I don't know if there's something else I should do. Any input would be appreciated.

P.S. I've done a bunch of basic things like cleaning up my packages, uninstalling the postgresql packages, restarting the computer, and then attempting to reinstall them (as detailed [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=947124&p=5962046#post5962046) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2112427&p=12493624#post12493624)) but it's had no effect.

EDIT: The output of `sudo which install` is `/usr/local/bin/install`.

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo which install` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you downloaded or installed the `install` command of exercism.io into `/usr/local/bin`. Move it to another location that is not in your $PATH, or remove it if you don't need it anymore.